# How to update total balance with case

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table. I want to update NewBalance after CR and DR.

```
id  amount  trs_typ NewBalance
1   10  DR  500
2   11  DR  563
3   25  CR  256
4   65  DR  354
5   58  CR  658
6   45  CR  542
7   65  DR  322
```

```sql
UPDATE test 
SET Total=(CASE 
   WHEN transection_type = 'CR' THEN total+amount 
   WHEN transection_type='DR' THEN Total-amount 
END)
```

```
id  amount  trs_typ NewBalance
1   10  DR  399
2   11  DR  410
3   25  CR  385
4   65  DR  360
5   58  CR  425
6   45  CR  367
7   65  DR  322
```

from bottom

322+45 = 367

Comment: your question is not clear. Please be specific about your issue.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: It seems odd that you calculate a running total in reverse order of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a running total in reverse order of ID. You can achieve this using a variable to store the running balance.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id  int,amount int,  trs_typ varchar(2), NewBalance int);
insert into t values
(1  , 10 , 'DR' , 500),
(2  , 11 , 'DR' , 563),
(3  , 25 , 'CR' , 256),
(4  , 65 , 'DR' , 354),
(5  , 58 , 'CR' , 658),
(6  , 45 , 'CR' , 542),
(7  , 65 , 'DR' , 322);

update t set newbalance = 0 where id <> (select maxid from (select max(id) maxid from t) s);

update t join(
select t.*,
        if(newbalance > 0 ,@rb:=newbalance,if(trs_typ = 'cr',@rb:=@rb+amount,@rb:=@rb - amount)) rb
from t 
cross join(select @rb:=0) rb
order by id desc
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.newbalance = t1.rb
;

select * from t;

+------+--------+---------+------------+
| id   | amount | trs_typ | NewBalance |
+------+--------+---------+------------+
|    1 |     10 | DR      |        364 |
|    2 |     11 | DR      |        374 |
|    3 |     25 | CR      |        385 |
|    4 |     65 | DR      |        360 |
|    5 |     58 | CR      |        425 |
|    6 |     45 | CR      |        367 |
|    7 |     65 | DR      |        322 |
+------+--------+---------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the newbalance for ids 1 and 2 differ from your expected output (I think correctly)

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working fine now..